# Extract last word in string before the first comma

Tags: r, string

I have a list of names like "Mark M. Owens, M.D., M.P.H." that I would like to sort to first name, last names and titles. With this data, titles always start after the first comma, if there is a title.

I am trying to sort the list into:

`FirstName LastName Titles
Mark       Owens     M.D.,M.P.H
Lara       Kraft     -
Dale       Good      C.P.A`

Thanks in advance.

Here is my sample code:

```
namelist <- c("Mark M. Owens, M.D., M.P.H.", "Dale C. Good, C.P.A", "Lara T. Kraft" , "Roland G. Bass, III")
firstnames=sub('^?(\\w+)?.*$','\\1',namelist)
lastnames=sub('.*?(\\w+)\\W+\\w+\\W*?$', '\\1', namelist)
titles = sub('.*,\\s*', '', namelist)
names <- data.frame(firstnames , lastnames, titles )
```

You can see that with this code, Mr. Owens is not behaving. His title starts after the last comma, and the last name begins from P. You can tell that I referred to [Extract last word in string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658216/extract-last-word-in-string-in-r), [Extract 2nd to last word in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363688/extract-2nd-to-last-word-in-string) and [Extract last word in a string after comma if there are multiple words else the first word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148828/extract-last-word-in-a-string-after-comma-if-there-are-multiple-words-else-the-f)

Comment: How should the string `"Roland G. Bass, III"` look in the final output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were off to a good start so you should pick up from there. The `firstnames` variable was good as written. For `lastnames` I used a modified name list. Inside of the sub function is another that eliminates everything after the first comma. The last name will then be the final word in the string. For `titles` there is a two-step process of first eliminating everything before the first comma, then replacing non-matched strings with a hyphen `-`.

```
namelist <- c("Mark M. Owens, M.D., M.P.H.", "Dale C. Good, C.P.A", "Lara T. Kraft" , "Roland G. Bass, III")
firstnames=sub('^?(\\w+)?.*$','\\1',namelist)
lastnames <- sub(".*?(\\w+)$", "\\1", sub(",.*", "", namelist), perl=TRUE)
titles <- sub(".*?,", "", namelist)
titles <- ifelse(titles == namelist, "-", titles)

names <- data.frame(firstnames , lastnames, titles )
  firstnames lastnames        titles
1       Mark     Owens  M.D., M.P.H.
2       Dale      Good         C.P.A
3       Lara     Kraft             -
4     Roland      Bass           III
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, at least on test data:

```
x=strsplit(namelist,split = ",")
x=rapply(object = x,function(x) gsub(pattern = "^ ",replacement = "",x =     x),how="replace")

names=sapply(x,function(y) y[[1]])
titles=sapply(x,function(y) if(length(unlist(y))>1){
    paste(na.omit(unlist(y)[2:length(unlist(y))]),collapse = ",")
}else{""})
names=strsplit(names,split=" ")
firstnames=sapply(names,function(y) y[[1]])
lastnames=sapply(names,function(y) y[[3]])

names <- data.frame(firstnames, lastnames, titles )
names
```

In cases like this, when the structure of strings is always the same, it is easier to use functions like strsplit() to extract desired parts